# Python array/list resetting inside loop

Tags: python, arrays

```
from collections import deque
import itertools
lfsr = deque([])
taps = []
i=0
x=0
y=0
test=''

for i in itertools.product([0,1],repeat=15):
    lfsr = deque(i)
    #print(lfsr)
    while x < len(lfsr):
        while y < len(lfsr):
            taps = [x, y]
            #print (lfsr)
            y+=1
        x+=1
```

Sorry for repost.

I have a simplified version of my code above with the same problem. I am trying to set the lfsr list equal to a binary number, once this is being set i want to use this value within the nested loops. The lfsr is being set correctly i believe as when i uncomment out the first #print, it prints as it should, however when i try to print it during the nested loop, all it outputs is 0's.

What is causing the array/list to be set to 0 and changing from when its initially set?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't getting reset.  The problem is your loop control.  Since you never reset `x` and `y` to 0, the only time you enter your `while` loops is when the dequeue is all `0`s.

```
from collections import deque
import itertools
lfsr = deque([])
taps = []
i=0 
test=''

for i in itertools.product([0,1],repeat=4):
    # reduced length to 4, to see the effects more easily

    lfsr = deque(i)
    print("TOP", lfsr)
    limit = len(lfsr)
    x=0
    while x < limit:
        y=0
        while y < limit:
            taps = [x, y]
            print ("MID", lfsr)
            y+=1
        x+=1
```

Convert to `for` loops (which are the proper structure) to make this easier.

```
for i in itertools.product([0,1],repeat=4):
    lfsr = deque(i)
    print("TOP", lfsr)
    limit = len(lfsr)

    for x in range(limit):
        for y in range(limit):
            taps = [x, y]
            print ("MID", lfsr)
```